# MySQL big limit number versus no limit

Tags: mysql, optimization

I was wondering what would be faster and what's the tradeoffs of using one or the other query?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE somecolumn = 'something' LIMIT 999;
```

vs.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE somecolumn = 'something';
```

Now, considering that the results of the query will never return more than a couple of hundreds of rows, does using `LIMIT 999` makes some significate performance impact or not?

I'm looking into this option as in my project I will have some kind of option for a user to limit results as he'd like, and he can leave limit empty to show all, so it's easier for me to leave LIMIT part of the query and then just to change the number.

Now, the table is really big, ranging from couple of hundreds of thousands to couple of millions rows.
The exact quesy looks something like:

```
SELECT  SUM(revenue) AS cost,
        IF(ISNULL(headline) OR  headline = '', 'undefined', headline
           ) AS headline
    FROM  `some_table`
    WHERE  ((date >= '2017-01-01')
       AND  (date <= '2017-12-31')
           )
      AND          -- (sic)
    GROUP BY  `headline`
    ORDER BY  `cost` DESC
```

As I said before, this query will never return more than about a hundred rows.

Comment: It depends on how many rows are actually in the table, the performance will be slower by how many records > 999.

Comment: I think you could test this for yourself quicker than asking us.

Comment: If you are sure that there would never be more than 999 rows in the result, Using LIMIT would have no impact on the performance.

Comment: @SPlatten I added more info to the question

Comment: @Strawberry Yes I could test, but I could see no difference now, I'm asking this how it works in general, so that I can know what to expect when data changes and to understand it even more. And possibly if it could impact the performance negatively or positively with indexes or without...

Comment: @Imaginaroom, one thing to be aware of is that the SQL server will cache queries so if you perform the same query twice, the 2nd time will be very much faster.

Comment: A tiny overhead would be introduced to monitor the limit (otherwise the limit could not work) but the differential is almost certainly too tiny to detect reliably. Having now said that almost invariably someone will find me wrong, but anyway, if you apply a limit you do protect yourself from some rouge query error that might otherwise send many more rows that you want to handle, and the "cost" to do that will be negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Disk I/O, if any, is by far the most costly part of a query.
- Fetching each row ranks next.
- Almost everything else is insignificant.

However, *if* the existence of `LIMIT` can *change* what the Optimizer does, *then* there could be a significant difference.

- In most cases, including the queries you gave, a too-big `LIMIT` has not impact.
- In *certain subqueries*, a `LIMIT` will prevent the elimination of `ORDER BY`.  A subquery is, by definition, is a set not an ordered set.  So `LIMIT` is a kludge to prevent the optimization of removing `ORDER BY`.
- *If* there is a composite index that includes all the columns needed for `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, *and* `ORDER BY`, then the Optimizer can stop when the `LIMIT` is reached.  Other situations go through tmp tables and sorts for `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` and can do the `LIMIT` only against a full set of rows.

Two caches were alluded to in the Comments so far.

- "Query cache" -- This records exact queries and their result sets.  *If* it is turned on *and* if it applicable, then the query comes back "instantly".  By "exact", I include the existence and value of `LIMIT`.
- To speed up all queries, data and indexes blocks are "cached" in RAM (see `innodb_buffer_pool_size`).  This avoids disk I/O when a *similar* (not necessarily exact) query is run.  See my first sentence, above.